# Change value in bidimensional array

Tags: python

I have this array `array = [['F', 'F', 'D', 'X', 'A', 'A'], ['F', 'A', 'G', 'F', 'F', 'D'], ['A', 'G', 'F', 'F', 0, 0]]`.

I dont know how to replace the 0's in the last row of the arry with the letter "X". How can I do that?

Comment: replace with what?

Comment: @shivankgtm sry i edited the question now, forgot to say it

Comment: By iterating over it, checking and replacing?

Comment: @gre_gor yes, like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you can do it with list comprehensions and a ternary operator:

```
infos = [['F', 'F', 'D', 'X', 'A', 'A'], ['F', 'A', 'G', 'F', 'F', 'D'], ['A', 'G', 'F', 'F', 0, 0]]

result = []
for info in infos:
    result.append(['X' if x ==0 else x for x in info])


print(result)
```

You can read about [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and the [ternary operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html) in their respective documentation.

Output:

```
[['F', 'F', 'D', 'X', 'A', 'A'], ['F', 'A', 'G', 'F', 'F', 'D'], ['A', 'G', 'F', 'F', 'X', 'X']]
```

Comment: You can use an additional list comprehension to get a one-liner: `result = [['X' if x ==0 else x for x in info] for info in infos]`

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [['F', 'F', 'D', 'X', 'A', 'A'], ['F', 'A', 'G', 'F', 'F', 'D'], ['A', 'G', 'F', 'F', 0, 0]]

for i in range(len(arr)):
    for j in range(len(arr[i])):
        if arr[i][j]==0:
            arr[i][j]='X'
print(arr)
```

To replace any zeros in the 2 dimensional list with character X